# Cumulative Line in Pine Script

Tags: pine-script, cumulative-sum, algorithmic-trading, cumulative-line-chart

I am new to Pine Script. I am trying to make a cumulative line starting at 10000 using the value obtained by subtracting to the value of the Open of a Daily candle the value of the previous Daily Close.

```
study("Cumulative Line", overlay=false)

apertura = open[0]
cierre = close[1]

suma = 10000.0
suma := suma + (open[0] - close[1]) + 10000.0

plot(suma)
```

I have tried making a SMA with a length of 1. Nevertheless, this is the error I got:

**Script could not be translated from: |B|suma := suma + (open**

I have tried without making the cumulative line and just ploting a SMA with the values of the difference between the daily candle's open minus the previous daily candle's close and it works. Basically, I do not know how to make a cumulative line of those values, can anybody help me? Thank you anyway for your time

Answer (score 0):

`:=` operator doesn't work in pinescript version 1 (default if not explicitly mentioned in the script)

Add `//@version=4` at the beginning of the script:

```
//@version=4
study("Cumulative Line", overlay=false)

apertura = open[0]
cierre = close[1]

suma = 10000.0
suma := suma + (open[0] - close[1]) + 10000.0

plot(suma)
```